# How to handle empty python tuples in postgresql query

Tags: python, postgresql

When pulling data from another data source, I've stored them in multiple tuples. Arbitrarily some of these tuples can be empty depending on the scenarios where I pull them from, the problem with this is that when it's empty i can't pass the tuple in the "Where in" clause of postgresql or else there will be an error. I want to know what is the best way to handle the empty ones... this is written in python and postgresql

```
at_level_1 = tuple(item1)
at_level_2 = tuple(empty)
at_level_3 = tuple(item3)

n_level_1 = tuple(data1)
n_level_2 = tuple(data2)
n_level_3 = tuple(empty)


query = """
select SOURCE_NUMBER, BOOK_NET
from BOOKING.BV_DETAIL
where (S_LEVEL_1 IN {} or S_LEVEL_2 IN {} or S_LEVEL_3 IN {}) and (S_LEVEL_1_DESCR IN {} or S_LEVEL_2_DESCR IN {} or S_LEVEL_3_DESCR IN {})
""".format(at_level_1, at_level_2, at_level_3, n_level_1, n_level_2, n_level_3)
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Do not inject values in an SQL query using python's string.format(). It's psycopg's responsability to do that (and handle escaping characters, prevent SQL injection, ...). See https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#query-parameters .

Comment: will that solve my problem ?

Comment: Looks like psycopg2 doesn't handle empty tuple in this case (it's not clear if it should raise an error or filter the whole 'xyz IN ()' anyway). You could try using `WHERE (S_LEVEL_1 = ANY(%s) ...)` instead, which will handle empty lists correctly (ie not match anything).